# I can't cycle through all the controls in the window, including tabs

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, tabs

I've been trying to work with tab control for a long time.
I came to the next problem, and it is:
I can't cycle through all the controls, including tabs.
If I create the tab control with

```
WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT
```

I CAN cycle through all child controls, but the cycle skips tabs.
If I remove WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, then the opposite is true:
I CAN'Т cycle through child controls, but I can cycle through tabs.
This is [my winapi test form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrhKM.png).
The "Tab ?" and "Button Clear" buttons are children of the main window.
All pane windows are children of the tab control.
Each "Button 1", "Button 2" and "Button 3" group is child of each pane window.
What I want the form to do is cycle controls in the following order or similar, but also include tabs:
Tab 1 -> Button 1 -> Button 2 -> Button 3 -> Button Clear ->
Tab 2 -> Button 1 -> Button 2 -> Button 3 -> Button Clear ->
Tab 3 -> Button 1 -> Button 2 -> Button 3 -> Button Clear -> Tab 1...
I also add my test program, which consists of only one file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#define TAB_ITEMS 3
#define BUTTONS_PER_PANE 3
#define IDS_PER_PANE 20

typedef enum {
    id_tab = 100,
    id_pane,
    id_group_box,
    id_first_button,
    id_edit = 1000,
    id_clear
} controls_id;

#define PANE_ID(pane) (id_pane + pane * IDS_PER_PANE)
#define GR_BOX_ID(pane) (id_group_box + pane * IDS_PER_PANE)
#define BUTTON_ID(pane,num) (id_first_button + pane * IDS_PER_PANE + num)

HWND hWin, hTab, hPane[ TAB_ITEMS ];
LONG_PTR def_comctl_proc = NULL;
int current_pane_id = 0;
int new_pane_id = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK PaneProc( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    if( Msg == WM_COMMAND ) {
        WORD button = LOWORD( wParam );
        int ind; // Get pane index
        for( ind = 0; ind < TAB_ITEMS; ind++ ) if( hWnd == hPane[ ind ] ) break;
        // Check and find the pressed button
        if( button >= BUTTON_ID( ind, 0 ) && button < BUTTON_ID( ind, BUTTONS_PER_PANE ) ) {
            TCHAR bff[ 32 ];
            _stprintf_s( bff, _T("Pane %u, Button %u"), ind + 1, (button - BUTTON_ID( ind, 0 )) + 1 );
            SetDlgItemText( hWin, id_edit, bff );
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return CallWindowProc( ( WNDPROC )def_comctl_proc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam );
}

void CreateControls( HWND hWnd ) {
    HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    TCHAR bff[ 32 ];
    TCITEM tie;
    int dx, dy, tdx, tdy;
    RECT rc, rc_tab;

    GetClientRect( hWnd, &rc ); dx = rc.right - rc.left; dy = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    // Create tab control
    hTab = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_TABCONTROL, _T(""),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP, 0, 0 ,dx, 120,
        hWnd, ( HMENU )id_tab, hInst, NULL );

    // Create tab items with group box and buttons
    for( int i = 0; i < TAB_ITEMS; i++ ) {
        // Insert Item
        ZeroMemory( &tie, sizeof( TCITEM ) );
        _stprintf_s( bff, _T("Tab %u"), i + 1 );
        tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE;
        tie.pszText = bff;
        tie.iImage = -1;
        TabCtrl_InsertItem( hTab, i, &tie );

        // Create tab item pane
        GetClientRect( hTab, &rc_tab ); tdx = rc_tab.right - rc_tab.left; tdy = rc_tab.bottom - rc_tab.top;
        TabCtrl_AdjustRect( hTab, FALSE, &rc_tab );
        hPane[ i ] = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_STATIC, _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP,
            rc_tab.left, rc_tab.top, rc_tab.right - rc_tab.left, rc_tab.bottom - rc_tab.top,
            hTab, ( HMENU )PANE_ID( i ), hInst, NULL );

        // Set new Pane window procedure
        def_comctl_proc = SetWindowLongPtr( hPane[ i ], GWLP_WNDPROC, ( LONG_PTR )PaneProc );

        // Create group box in each tab item pane
        _stprintf_s( bff, _T("Pane %u controls"), i + 1 );
        CreateWindowEx( NULL, WC_BUTTON, bff,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_GROUPBOX, 10, 10, 10 + BUTTONS_PER_PANE*80, 70,
            hPane[ i ], ( HMENU )GR_BOX_ID( i ), hInst, NULL );

        // Create buttons in each tab item pane
        for( int j = 0; j < BUTTONS_PER_PANE; j++ ) {
            _stprintf_s( bff, _T("Button\r\n--- &%u ---"), j + 1 );
            CreateWindowEx( NULL, WC_BUTTON, bff,
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | BS_MULTILINE, 20 + j*80, 30, 70, 40,
                hPane[ i ], ( HMENU )BUTTON_ID( i, j ), hInst, NULL );
        }

        // Show only first pane controls
        ShowWindow( hPane[ i ], i ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW );
    }
    TabCtrl_SetCurSel( hTab, 0 );

    // Create edit box for messages
    CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_EDIT, _T(""),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY, 10, 130, 200, 20,
        hWnd, ( HMENU )id_edit, hInst, NULL );

    // Create Clear Button
    CreateWindowEx( NULL, WC_BUTTON, _T("&Clear"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 220, 129, 70, 22,
        hWnd, ( HMENU )id_clear, hInst, NULL );
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    switch( Msg ) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateControls( hWnd );
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if( LOWORD( wParam ) == id_clear ) SetDlgItemText( hWin, id_edit, _T("") );
            break;

        case WM_NOTIFY: {
            NMHDR& nmh = *( LPNMHDR )lParam;
            if( nmh.idFrom == id_tab ) {
                switch( nmh.code ) {
                    case TCN_SELCHANGING:
                        return FALSE;
                    case TCN_SELCHANGE:
                        new_pane_id = TabCtrl_GetCurSel( nmh.hwndFrom );
                        ShowWindow( hPane[ current_pane_id ], SW_HIDE );
                        ShowWindow( hPane[ new_pane_id ], SW_SHOW );
                        SetFocus( GetDlgItem( hPane[ new_pane_id ], id_first_button + new_pane_id*IDS_PER_PANE ) );
                        current_pane_id = new_pane_id;
                        break;
                }
                return TRUE;
            } }
            return FALSE;
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return FALSE;
}

LPCTSTR ClsName = _T("Tab_Control_Tester");
LPCTSTR WndName = _T("Tab Control Tester");

INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {
    MSG         Msg;
    WNDCLASSEX  WndClsEx;
    RECT        rc;
    int         dx = 320, dy = 200;

    WndClsEx.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WndClsEx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    WndClsEx.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcedure;
    WndClsEx.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    WndClsEx.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    WndClsEx.hIcon         = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    WndClsEx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    WndClsEx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BTNSHADOW;
    WndClsEx.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    WndClsEx.lpszClassName = ClsName;
    WndClsEx.hInstance     = hInstance;
    WndClsEx.hIconSm       = NULL;

    RegisterClassEx(&WndClsEx);

    {
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc = { sizeof( INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ), ICC_WIN95_CLASSES };
        InitCommonControlsEx( &icc );
    }

    Msg.wParam = 0;

    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(),&rc);
    if( rc.right < dx ) dx = rc.right - 96;
    if( rc.bottom < dy ) dy = rc.bottom - 96;
    hWin = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, ClsName, WndName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        ( rc.right - dx ) / 2, ( rc.bottom - dy ) / 2, dx, dy, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
    if( !hWin ) goto _exit_WinMain;

    ShowWindow( hWin, SW_SHOWNORMAL );
    UpdateWindow( hWin );

    while( GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) ) {
        if( !IsDialogMessage( hWin, &Msg) ) {
            TranslateMessage( &Msg );
            DispatchMessage (&Msg );
        }
    }

_exit_WinMain:
    return (int)Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Don't create the controls as child windows. Create them as siblings of the tab control, but with a higher z-order so they draw on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! What you offer is not desirable. The idea is to arrange all controls from one tab on one pane as children so that they can be easily shown and hidden, and the pane must be child of the tab control, otherwise it cannot receive the necessary messages.

Comment: You can embed the controls into a single parent marked `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`, and that single parent is a sibling of the tab control. This is how the standard property sheet control works. You can use Spy to see how it's put together. A parent cannot participate in the tab order of its children.

Comment: @RaymondChen, it doesn't happen that way. In your way, the controls are stacked on top of each other - becomes a complete mess. If you want, see the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-tab-control-in-the-main-window) of Microsoft. We do it the same way.

Comment: I'll have to have the example fixed. It "works" because a static control can't have focus, so the fact that you can't tab to the static control doesn't affect the sample. Yes, the controls are stacked on top of each other, but all but one of them is hidden. You use the tab control to decide which one to show, and hide the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the program works the way I want!
@RaymondChen was right: tab control and the static ( pane ) control must be siblings.
Here's what I changed:

---

Row 76: ***hTab*** → ***hWnd*** -  Now Tab control and Pane are siblings.

```
// OLD
hTab, ( HMENU )PANE_ID( i ), hInst, NULL );
// NEW
hWnd, ( HMENU )PANE_ID( i ), hInst, NULL );
```

---

Row 74: I removed ***WS_CLIPSIBLINGS*** and ***WS_TABSTOP***, because WS_TABSTOP doesn't work with static control and because tab control has WS_CLIPSIBLINGS already.

```
// OLD
hPane[ i ] = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_STATIC, _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP,
// NEW
hPane[ i ] = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_STATIC, _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
```

---

Row 57: I removed ***WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT*** from Tab control, because he has no more children.

```
// OLD
hTab = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_TABCONTROL, _T(""),
// NEW
hTab = CreateWindowEx( 0, WC_TABCONTROL, _T(""),
```

---

Row 131: I removed the whole line because it's pointless

```
SetFocus( GetDlgItem( hPane[ new_pane_id ], id_first_button + new_pane_id*IDS_PER_PANE ) );
```

---

[You can see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZBbH.gif)

Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse all child controls through the [`EnumChildWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) function.

However, it should be noted that your clear button and the other three buttons are not in the same control, so you cannot loop as you requested (traverse the clear every time).

At the same time, you can only traverse the tab control once. If you need to traverse the tab control, you need to traverse the tab control additionally.